# Bin and sum over time for precipitation data in CSV form

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a large CSV file with this formatting: month, year, lat, long, rainfall

How do I bin and sum over time by year? Also, different Q, how do I separate the data out into three bins of rainfalls in different basins?

Answer (score 0):

it will better if you can post a example of the data frame you have, but something like this might work:

```
# read into data frame
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_path')
# groupby year and get sum
df.groupby('year')['rainfall'].sum().reset_index(name='rainfall_sum)
```

for grouping into basins, I assume you need to make a scatter plot first, you might need a clustering algorithm. take a look at various algorithm in sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html